# mounting cephfs with secretfile

Tags: mount, ceph

I'm trying to mount cephfs and it's ok with password:

`mount -t ceph ceph-mon:6789:/docker /mnt/cephfs -o name=admin,secret=admin-pass`

However, if I use secretfile, it fails:

`mount -t ceph ceph-mon:6789:/docker /mnt/cephfs -o name=admin,secretfile=/etc/ceph/admin.secret`

The error message shows:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on ceph-mon:6789:/docker,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

And `dmesg|tail` shows

`libceph: bad option at 'secretfile=/etc/ceph/admin.secret'`

My ceph client version is 0.94 and the system is centos6.5.

How can I mount cephfs with secretfile?

Comment: solve this issue by installing `ceph-fuse`

Answer (score 6):

Finally found the solution in the ceph-users mailing list.
On Debian, the package `ceph-fs-common` needs to be installed.
Source: http://lists.ceph.com/pipermail/ceph-users-ceph.com/2013-July/032321.html

Comment: In case you're using Ubuntu, you can install the package by
```sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ceph-common```